# is there a shorter possibility to exclude directories in find command?

Tags: bash, find

It works but it is way too long, I even have more directories (different numbers) I want to exclude. Is there any possibility to make it shorter?

```
find ./8*/dti_processed/dti_FA.nii.gz \
     -not -path "./86*/*" -not -path "./852/*" -not -path "./853/*" \
     -not -path "./854/*" -not -path "./855/*" -not -path "./856/*" \
     -not -path "./857/*" -not -path "./858/*" -not -path "./859/*"
```

Comment: How about listing all matches and the filtering the list with `grep`?

Comment: thanks for your input! could you please give me an example? (i am new to programming)

Comment: `find -not -path "./86*/*" -not -path "./85[23456789]/*"`

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf this works for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a bracket expression to reduce the number of patterns:

```
find ./8*/dti_processed/dti_FA.nii.gz -not -path "./86*/*" -not -path "./85[2-9]/*"
```

Since you are using `bash`, it may be cleaner to use an array to hold a list of arguments for `find`, if you can't easily reduce your exclusions to a short list. This combines well with [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), which states that `not A and not B and ... and not Z == not (A or B or ... or Z)`:

```
exclude=(
    -path "./86*/*"
    -o -path "./852/*"
    -o -path "./853/*"
    -o -path "./854/*"
    -o -path "./855/*"
    -o -path "./856/*"
    -o -path "./857/*"
    -o -path "./858/*"
    -o -path "./859/*"
)
find .8*/dti_processed/dti_FA.nii.gz -not \( "${exclude[@]}" \)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions to filter the paths you don't want. Ie. your example command could be written as:

```
find ./8*/dti_processed/dti_FA.nii.gz -regextype egrep -not -regex '^\./(86.?|85[2-9])/'
```

The default regular expression type used by find is [Emacs Regular Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html). The `-regextype` flag changes this to [Egrep Regular Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/egrep-regular-expression-syntax.html).

Comment: Note that `-regex` isn't specified by POSIX. In fact, regexes are a bit of an overkill in this case, glob patterns are enough: `-not -path "./86*/*" -not -path "./85[23456789]/*"`